# Call to undefined function pcntl_wifsignaled()

Tags: php, pcntl

I'm attempting to use the import functionality in mediawiki 1.27.0, but I'm getting the error message:

```
Call to undefined function pcntl_wifsignaled() in extensions/Scribunto/engines/LuaStandalone/LuaStandaloneEngine.php on line 645
```

I'm running PHP version 5.6.30 on Ubuntu 14.0.4 with Apache2.4.7. I've followed various bits on information to install pcntl module and to the best of my knowledge the module is operational. phpinfo reports that pcntl is enabled. I have also commented out the line in php.ini regarding disabled_functions. Below are some reports from various bits of Ubuntu to explain the current config.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Installed php modules:**

```
$ php -me
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
XCache
XCache Cacher
XCache Coverager
XCache Optimizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib
```

**Disabled PHP functions:**

```
$ php -i | grep disable_functions
disable_functions => no value => no value
```

Comment: Apache doesn't use the command-line PHP interpreter.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Unfortunately that doesn't help with the answer. The PCNTL module is being loaded for use by apache. I have followed the instructions in http://php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php.

Comment: EDIT: I just saw this post on the 'related' listing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026153/call-to-undefined-function-pcntl-fork-php-fpm-nginx?rq=1 I guess this is what Alvaro was talking about, but given that the mediawiki core code is calling this function I should be able to operate somehow. It clearly works on Wikipedia...

Comment: I know nothing about the pcntl extension (thus I left a comment rather than an answer) but you were inspecting command-line PHP extensions to determine what extensions are available to a web app. And next time just say "I don't understand what you mean, could you please explain it?", rather than "it doesn't help". We programmer's have feelings too ;-)